# Go: How to create a server which can serve urls described in config file

Tags: http, go

could anyone help me here please as I'm new to golang? I have a yaml file which looks like this:

```yaml
port: 5000
handlers:
  - name: test1
    uri: /api/test1
    response:
      status: 200
      body: test1
  - name: test2
    uri: /api/test2
    response:
      status: 500
      body: test2
```

based on this file I want to create a server. Currently I'm trying to do it this way, but looks like it doesn't work as expected.
What am I doing wrong and what is the better way to achieve what I need?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func main() {
    config := parseYaml("conf.yaml")
    configHandlers := config.Handlers
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    for _, handler := range *configHandlers {
        mux.HandleFunc(*handler.Uri, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            w.WriteHeader(*handler.Response.Status)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, *handler.Response.Body)
        })
    }
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", *config.Port), mux))
}

type YamlConfig struct {
    Port     *string          `yaml:"port"`
    Handlers *[]HandlerConfig `yaml:"handlers"`
}

type HandlerConfig struct {
    Uri      *string   `yaml:"uri"`
    Name     *string   `yaml:"name"`
    Response *Response `yaml:"response"`
}

type Response struct {
    Status *int    `yaml:"status"`
    Body   *string `yaml:"body"`
}

func (c *YamlConfig) parseYaml(data []byte) error {
    return yaml.Unmarshal(data, c)
}

func parseYaml(path string) YamlConfig {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var config YamlConfig
    if err := config.parseYaml(data); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return config
}
```

Update:
If I run this server then regardless of which endpoint I hit, it will always return me `500` and `test2` in body

Comment: Erm... please check the help section of this site. When asking a question, it's important to be specific both in what the problem is, and what you've tried so far to solve it. As it stands, this question isn't so much a question as it is a request for someone else to write the code for you. Also `mux := *http.NewServeMux()`, why dereference that pointer? What is `parseYaml` doing? There's not enough here to work out the underlying issue...

Comment: my understanding is that mux pointer here doesn't make any difference. `parseYaml()` function just parses yaml config and provides list of handler objects which have `name`, `uri`, `response`, etc properties. Asking this question I want to understand as if my approach by setting handlers in FOR loop like this `mux.HandleFunc(...)` is correct and should work. Or if there are other approaches for this problem I would like to know them

Comment: The code you posted here is very minimal. At first glance, nothing really jumps out as being incorrect, but I'd need to see more (including what `parseYaml` does, and what the `handlers` variable/type looks like). If I'd have to hazard a guess, I'd say you're probably accessing the `handler` variable in the function you pass to `mux.HandlerFunc`, but `handler` gets reassigned in the loop, so all handler functions will end up using the same `handler` value

Comment: Sorry probably I was not clear enough in my question. I have provided the whole code. I expect that if I hit `/api/test1` it should return me `200` and `test1` and if I hit  `/api/test2` it should return `500` and `test2` but  regardless of which endpoint I hit it always returns me `500` and `test2` in body.

Comment: Yup, so my guess was correct: your handler function is accessing `handler.Response.Body` and the like. The `handler` variable comes from higher scope (the `for`) loop, and is reassigned on each iteration, so all of your handlers will respond with the last value `handler` was assigned, hence the behaviour. I'll post the solution in a response

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/OAie5p86HD7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is seemingly a common pitfall for people:

```
configHandlers := config.Handlers
mux := http.NewServeMux()
for _, handler := range *configHandlers {
    mux.HandleFunc(*handler.Uri, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(*handler.Response.Status)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, *handler.Response.Body)
    })
}
```

The `for` loop, on each iteration, reassigns the `handler` variable. In the loop body, you create a new function and pass it to `mux.HandlerFun`. These function bodies kind of *inherit* the outer scope, and access this `handler` variable. The variable is reassigned outside of the functions, and thus the values each handler function has access to changes with it. What you can do to address the issue is mask the `handler` variable the loop uses, and create a scope that is unique to each handler. The classic way in languages like JavaScript (where this is - or used to be back when I wrote some JS - a common issue) is to wrap the code in an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```
for _, handler := range *configHandlers {
    func (handler *HandlerConfig) { // handler is now the argument passed to this function
        mux.HandleFunc(*handler.Uri, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            w.WriteHeader(*handler.Response.Status)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, *handler.Response.Body)
        })
    }(handler) // call the function with the _current_ value of handler
}
```

This is a tad messy, and because golang is properly block-scoped, you can just do this:

```
for _, handler := range *configHandlers {
    h := handler // create a variable in the inner scope
    mux.HandleFunc(*handler.Uri, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // now h will reference a copy unique to each iteration
        w.WriteHeader(*h.Response.Status)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, *h.Response.Body)
    })
}
```

That ought to fix it. I've noticed some weirdness with your use of pointers in the types you've added to your question, though... Fields like `Port` being of type `*string`? Why wouldn't you just use `string`? No Same for the `Body` and `Status` fields in the `Response` type. By changing them to plain `string`  fields you don't have to dereference them in your handler functions. It will look a lot cleaner.

A bigger worry is this field:

```
Handlers *[]HandlerConfig `yaml:"handlers"`
```

I'm not sure if you really know what the type of this field is, but it makes next to no sense. `Handlers` is now a pointer to a slice of `HandlerConfig` values. I'm assuming you wanted this field to be:

```
// Handlers is a slice of HandlerConfig values:
Handlers []HandlerConfig `yaml:"handlers"`
// or Handlers is a slice of pointers to HandlerConfig values
Handlers []*HandlerConfig `yaml:"handlers"`
```

Generally speaking, a pointer to a slice, *especially* in a config type is bad code.

Comment: Thank you this helped. Learned many new things today

Answer (score 0):

If you define a struct that will represent the configuration in your YAML file, you can unmarshall the yaml into an instantiated struct of that type using the [yaml](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2?utm_source=godoc) package.  From there, you can reference the fields in the struct as any other struct.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type YamlExample struct {
    FieldOne    string `yaml:"fieldOne"`
    NestedField struct {
        Name string `yaml:"name"`
    } `yaml:"nestedField"`
}

const YamlEx string = `
fieldOne: one
nestedField:
    name: nestedFieldName
`

func main() {
    var yamlE YamlExample

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(YamlEx), &yamlE)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", yamlE)
}
```

[Link to example.](https://goplay.tools/snippet/wLk55-W2K0-)

In your case, you'd probably want to handle the routes in a struct and then reference the fields in the struct for things like route name, how to handle the body of the request, etc.  If your YAML is stored in a file, you'll have to use something like the `io` package to read the file into a byte array that the YAML package can parse.  [See here for a reference.](https://gobyexample.com/reading-files)

Comment: From the snippet in the question, and the reply to my comments, I think the OP is unmarshalling the yaml into a struct of some sort already. I suspect the struct is either malformed, or the handler functions are accessing the `handler` variable, which is reassigned in the outer loop. It's equally likely that the problem is a combination of both these issues though... more details needed to answer I think

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as already mentioned my issue not with parsing yaml but with defining server handlers. You can take a look at my updated question

Comment: Good clarification from both parties! I believe Elias' answer above answers the question much more appropriately than mine.